# NodeJS string concatenation unusual behaviour

Tags: node.js, typescript, string-concatenation

I am trying to construct this string for printing one message.

```
"At position #[" + index + "][" + _subIndex + "] TLPHN_DVC_TYP " +
                                    + _telNum?.TelephoneDeviceType.toString() + " ,allowed " + telephoneDeviceTypeEnum.join(',');
```

from watch is VsCode:
where `index` =0;`_subIndex` =0;`telNum.TelephoneDeviceType` =Mobile;`telephoneEnum`=["Mobile","Landline"];

It's returning :

```
At position #[0][0] TLPHN_DVC_TYP NaN ,allowed Mobile,Landline
```

Full Code:

```
if (_telNum?.TelephoneDeviceType && !(telephoneDeviceTypeEnum.indexOf(_telNum.TelephoneDeviceType) > 0)){
    console.log( "At position #[" + index + "][" + _subIndex + "] TLPHN_DVC_TYP " +
                                        + _telNum?.TelephoneDeviceType.toString() + " ,allowed " + telephoneDeviceTypeEnum.join(','));
    }
```

the condition should not satisfy but not sure why it's going inside the if and NaN returning. any suggestion?

Comment: Is the a reason why you don't use string templates?

Comment: TelephoneDeviceType ????? and what is the expected result

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, question fixed. @Exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the two plus signs: `"] TLPHN_DVC_TYP " + + _telNum?// ...etc`. The second one is parsed as the unary +, or a conversion to number, which obviously fails. Compare:

```js
console.log("foo" + "bar"); 

console.log("foo" + + "bar");
```

Added #1:

```
if (_telNum?.TelephoneDeviceType && !(telephoneDeviceTypeEnum.indexOf(_telNum.TelephoneDeviceType) >= 0)){
    console.log( "At position #[" + index + "][" + _subIndex + "] TLPHN_DVC_TYP " +_telNum?.TelephoneDeviceType.toString() + " ,allowed " + telephoneDeviceTypeEnum.join(','));
    }
```